Cycling Line Colours with Pgfplot Cubic Spline Patches
Consider the following snippet:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usepgfplotslibrary{colorbrewer, patchplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{axis}[cycle list/Set2]
  \addplot+[patch, patch type=cubic spline, point meta=none, red] 
  coordinates {
   (-1,-1) (1,1) (-1/3,{(-1/3)^3}) (1/3,{(1/3)^3})
  };
 \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

which is based off the cubic spline patch example in the PGFPLOTS manual.  As expected it produces a red curve.  However, I am having trouble changing the colour to be one from a set.  For example swapping red for index of colormap=2 of Set2 causes the line to revert to black.
What is the correct means of applying a uniform colour from a colour map to all of the patches?

perhaps you could provide a page or section number. it is a large manual.

Section 5.9.1 "Additional patch types" which is towards the end.

\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usepgfplotslibrary{colorbrewer, patchplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot[patch, patch type=cubic spline, Set2-B] 
coordinates {(-1,-1) (1,1) (-1/3,{(-1/3)^3}) (1/3,{(1/3)^3})};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


